# Setting up Azure AD and GSuite with AWS cognito federated identities

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, azure-active-directory, federated-identity, google-workspace

How can you enable SSO for azure AD and G Suite using AWS cognito federated identities ?

I have attempted to do with SAML, but could not figure it out, would be preferable if the solution can be done using AWS itself without much complications

Comment: Did you try https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-saas-amazon-web-service-tutorial and http://blog.flux7.com/aws-best-practice-azure-ad-saml-authentication-configuration-for-aws-console or do you mean the reverse?

Answer (score 0):

I've actually answered this question for Azure AD here: [Howto add Azure AD as AWS Cognito Federated IdP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45791699/howto-add-azure-ad-as-aws-cognito-federated-idp)

The steps are quite long, but I've created a step-by-step tutorial on setting this up. There is a current bug within the AzureAD web console that prevents changing the App ID to a URN, but it can be worked around by modifying the parameter with AzureAD powershell.

See the following blog post here:

https://www.idea11.com.au/how-to-set-up-aws-cognito-federation-office365/